# Changing sys.modules caused an unexpected KeyError

Tags: python

Some automated tests in a larger system need to be able to import a module, and then restore `sys.modules` to its original condition.

But this code fragment:

```
import sys

sys.modules = dict(sys.modules)
import pickle
```

causes this `KeyError` in Python 3.6-3.8:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/python3.6/pickle.py", line 1562, in <module>
    from _pickle import (
KeyError: '_compat_pickle'
```

It seems as if only `pickle` and modules that depend on it like `multiprocessing` are affected.  I've investigated `_compat_pickle` - it's a module for pickling compatibility with Python 2 - but nothing jumps out that would cause this.

Is there a safe way to restore `sys.modules` back to an earlier state? And what is the mechanism behind this unexpected `KeyError`?

Comment: I can not reproduce this error with Python 3.6.9 on ubuntu

Comment: I could reproduce with 3.7.0 on windows. (Or similar errors, depending on what has been imported)

Comment: have you tried using `sys.modules.copy()` instead of calling `dict`?

Comment: Your description says you want to *restore* ``sys.modules``, but in fact you *replace* it. Have you tried to actually adjust the content of the original ``sys.modules``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: that is in fact the solution I'm using in the actual code, but it makes me nervous, because I have no guarantee that that's OK either.

Comment: @RobertKearns: I reproduced it on several clean environments on Mac OS and also on Travis, which uses Ubuntu: https://travis-ci.com/github/rec/gitz/jobs/328079397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sys.modules` is a lie (I think). It is not actually the true source of the modules dict. That is stored on a C level in the current interpreter, and `sys.modules` is just a copy to that. `_pickle` is special, since it imports a module from C source, which I assume leads to this error (mismatch between what `tstate->interp->modules` says is imported and what `sys.modules` thinks is imported).

<strike>This might be considered a bug in python. I am not sure if a bug report already exists.</strike> Here is the bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue12633 .

You could just save which keys are in modules before and after the code, and delete all other entries afterwards.

Comment: Your answer is convincing, but is there a guarantee that if I just use dictionary operations on `sys.modules`, that everything will be OK?

Comment: Yes. It *is* a dictionary, just stored at multiple locations.

Comment: So you are perhaps right that it's a bug - you shouldn't be allowed to assign to sys.modules at all.  I'll take a look to see if it's there and file it if not.

Comment: Looky looky - someone hit the same bug, for the same reason! https://bugs.python.org/issue12633

Comment: I was already thinking 'there should be a bug report for that', but didn't search long enough to find it.